# My app is serializing Db entities to de webservice layer. How to turn all to DTO?

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb

I have come to an application with some very big performance problems. The definition of the hibernate entities is practically all with EAGER definitions. I suppose that initially it was not a problem because they had few entities but there has come a time when the performance is tremendously bad.
I know how to fix the problem but these entities are published in the webservice layer.
I would like to break the application layers first before I start changing the Database model. being the entities in the presentation layer makes it very difficult to change.

I had thought of duplicating the DB entities in the webservice layer (with no references to the persistence layer). This way i would have created as many DTOs as entities.
Then use some framework like objectmapper or jmapper to convert them into the new DTO.

Before spending many hours doing it. Sounds like a good idea? Do you see any way to fix the problem easier?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A sample DTO model could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<RoleDto> getRoles();

    @EntityView(Role.class)
    interface RoleDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!